# How to exclude current date in a group by value rolling window execution in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing IDs, a date and numerical values. I group the data for each ID, and then I calculate the cumulative amount of the previous rows, with a time window of 30 days. In the dataframe below this has been accomplished using the code below (the actual dataframe contains more than one ID and more dates).

So in short the column SUM_AMOUNT is being created based on the other columns.

Code:

```
def get_rolling_amount(grp, freq, on_name, column_name):
    return grp.rolling(freq, on=on_name, closed='left')[column_name].sum()

df[new_column_name] = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False, group_keys=False)\
                         .apply(get_rolling_amount, '30D', 'DATE', 'AMOUNT')
```

Dataframe:

```
         ID       DATE                  AMOUNT                SUM_AMOUNT
111935   100000   2015-02-18            455.00                    NaN
111936   100000   2015-02-18            455.00                 455.00
111937   100000   2015-04-02            455.00                    NaN
111938   100000   2015-04-02            925.00                 455.00
111939   100000   2015-04-02           2780.00                1380.00
111940   100000   2015-04-09            895.00                4160.00
111941   100000   2015-04-09            425.00                5055.00
111942   100000   2015-04-09            425.00                5480.00
111943   100000   2015-04-09            925.00                5905.00
111944   100000   2015-04-09            455.00                6830.00
111947   100000   2015-05-21           1003.00                    NaN
111945   100000   2015-05-26            455.00                1003.00
111946   100000   2015-05-26            925.00                1458.00
111948   100000   2015-05-26            455.00                2383.00
111949   100000   2015-05-26           2780.00                2838.00
111950   100000   2015-05-26            425.00                5618.00
111951   100000   2015-05-26           1000.00                6043.00
111952   100000   2015-05-26            455.00                7043.00
111953   100000   2015-05-26            455.00                7498.00
111954   100000   2015-06-19            925.00                7953.00
111955   100000   2015-06-19           1820.00                8878.00
111956   100000   2015-06-19            925.00               10698.00
```

As you can see, per ID there are rows that have the same date. I cannot get the dates in a more detailed form. I don't want to take the values of same dates into account in the calculation, because I don't know what their order is if they are on the same date and the order is important.

**What I actually want**

I want to be able to get the cumulative sum of all data points that fall in the range of the last 30 days, **excluding the date of the current row**. 
I have changed the dataframe to reflect what I would like to have:

```
         ID       DATE                  AMOUNT                SUM_AMOUNT
111935   100000   2015-02-18            455.00                    NaN
111936   100000   2015-02-18            455.00                    NaN
111937   100000   2015-04-02            455.00                    NaN
111938   100000   2015-04-02            925.00                    NaN
111939   100000   2015-04-02           2780.00                    NaN
111940   100000   2015-04-09            895.00                4160.00
111941   100000   2015-04-09            425.00                4160.00
111942   100000   2015-04-09            425.00                4160.00
111943   100000   2015-04-09            925.00                4160.00
111944   100000   2015-04-09            455.00                4160.00
111947   100000   2015-05-21           1003.00                    NaN
111945   100000   2015-05-26            455.00                1003.00
111946   100000   2015-05-26            925.00                1003.00
111948   100000   2015-05-26            455.00                1003.00
111949   100000   2015-05-26           2780.00                1003.00
111950   100000   2015-05-26            425.00                1003.00
111951   100000   2015-05-26           1000.00                1003.00
111952   100000   2015-05-26            455.00                1003.00
111953   100000   2015-05-26            455.00                1003.00
111954   100000   2015-06-19            925.00                7953.00
111955   100000   2015-06-19           1820.00                7953.00
111956   100000   2015-06-19            925.00                7953.00
```

So if the row's date is 2015-06-19, I want to have the sum of all previous rows in a 30 day window, but rows that have the date of 2015-06-19 should not be included in that window.

One other important thing to mention is that I cannot collapse the rows to make one row per ID and DATE.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you make use of [DataFrame.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-dataframe-drop-duplicates). `... I cannot collapse the rows to make one row per ID and DATE.` - why??

Comment: IIUC, rows with index 111938 and 111937 should be `NaN`, no ?

Comment: @Ben.T You're right, fixed that.

Comment: @wwii For future processing I need to have every row seperately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have several values for a same day, I would say you should first [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) daily to get the `sum` per day and then [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) over the last 30 values prior to the date with the use of [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to not include today. Perform these operations per ID with a `groupby` and then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on the ID and DATE back in `df`.

```
df = df.merge( (df.groupby('ID').resample('1D', on='DATE').sum()['AMOUNT'].shift()
                  .rolling(30, min_periods=1).sum().fillna(0).reset_index()), 
               on = ['ID', 'DATE'], how='left', suffixes=('', '_SUM'))
```

and you get you `df` such as:

```
        DATE      ID  AMOUNT  AMOUNT_SUM
0  2015-02-18  100000   455.0         0.0
1  2015-02-18  100000   455.0         0.0
2  2015-04-02  100000   455.0         0.0
3  2015-04-02  100000   925.0         0.0
4  2015-04-02  100000  2780.0         0.0
5  2015-04-09  100000   895.0      4160.0
6  2015-04-09  100000   425.0      4160.0
7  2015-04-09  100000   425.0      4160.0
8  2015-04-09  100000   925.0      4160.0
9  2015-04-09  100000   455.0      4160.0
10 2015-05-21  100000  1003.0         0.0
11 2015-05-26  100000   455.0      1003.0
12 2015-05-26  100000   925.0      1003.0
13 2015-05-26  100000   455.0      1003.0
14 2015-05-26  100000  2780.0      1003.0
15 2015-05-26  100000   425.0      1003.0
16 2015-05-26  100000  1000.0      1003.0
17 2015-05-26  100000   455.0      1003.0
18 2015-05-26  100000   455.0      1003.0
19 2015-06-19  100000   925.0      7953.0
20 2015-06-19  100000  1820.0      7953.0
21 2015-06-19  100000   925.0      7953.0
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the out of the box thinking I needed. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate on the rows of your df and define a new mask each time :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : ["2015-02-18", "2015-02-18", "2015-04-02", "2015-04-02", "2015-04-02", "2015-04-09"],
                  'Amount' : [455, 455, 455, 925, 2780, 895]})
  Date  Amount
0  2015-02-18     455
1  2015-02-18     455
2  2015-04-02     455
3  2015-04-02     925
4  2015-04-02    2780
5  2015-04-09     895

# We make sure our type is date
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # We look on previous rows with dates within 30 days of our own
    mask = (df['Date'] <= row['Date']) & (df['Date'] >= row['Date'] - timedelta(days=30)) & (df.index<index)
    df.loc[index, 'sum'] = df.loc[mask,'Amount'].sum()
```

---

Output :

```
       Date  Amount     sum
0 2015-02-18     455     0.0
1 2015-02-18     455   455.0
2 2015-04-02     455     0.0
3 2015-04-02     925   455.0
4 2015-04-02    2780  1380.0
5 2015-04-09     895  4160.0
```

In your expected output you were not consistant in taking or ignoring the same day when summing the amounts. I included them but you can ignore them by changing the mask to :

```
# There is no need for the index condition either so we remove it
mask = (df['Date'] >= row['Date'] - timedelta(days=30))
```